# Command for guild counter

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i am new with js and I wanted to create a command or a log on the console that would tell me how many server discord my bot is in. How can I do? Can anyone please write me a code example? So I can understand how to create the future ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<Client>.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(<Client>.username + " is Online on " + <Client>.guilds.cache.size + " Servers")
}
```

Comment: how can I create a command without to restart the bot? Thanks in advance

Comment: @FM777 Not Possible. The Bot needs to be restarted after something new was created. Also, make sure to check the Checkmark below my Question if it helped you :)

Comment: How can I put it in the bot state? It's possible? For example : In x guilds... and after 10second Try .Help!

Comment: @FM777 Have u replaced <Client>?

Comment: Yes sure. But is possible to use the rich status for show the guild?

Comment: @FM777 i dont think so

Comment: Always ^^ @FM777

Comment: Do u have discord? Because i have another question and i can't open a chat with u on stack

Comment: @FM777 Yes i do Aspx.#2179

Answer (score 0):

[${client.guilds.size}](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=size) get number guilds

[${client.users.size}](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=size) get number members all guilds

```js
client.on('ready', message => {
  client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.size} servers have ${client.users.size} members`+` | !help `, { type: 'WATCHING' })
  console.log(`${client.guilds.size} servers have ${client.users.size} members`) 
 });
```

Comment: It is wrong. It will return undefined. Tho. Why you need the Message Parameter in an Ready Event?

Comment: It wrong becaues you didn't tell version of discord.js

Answer (score 0):

## Discord.js Verison 11.4.2

```js
if(message.content === '!activity'){
 client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.size} servers have ${client.users.size} members`+` | !help `, { type: 'WATCHING' })
}
```

## Discord.js Version 12

```js
if(message.content === '!activity'){
 client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.cache.size} servers have ${client.users.cache.size} members`+` | !help `, { type: 'WATCHING' })
}
```

Comment: Why I can't do if him want to help?

If has answer then I can't answer????